The sufficient statistic and unbiased estimator of normal variance
Suppose we have a normal distribution with mean $\theta_1$ and variance $\theta_2$.
I know that $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2$ is an unbaised estimator of $\theta_2$ and has a variance $2\theta_2^2/(n-1)$ but I have few questions about some facts I found with no proof

Why is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ is unbiased estimator with variance $2\theta_2^2/n$ when $\theta_1=0$? I mean why did $\frac{1}{n-1}$ become $\frac{1}{n}$?
I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ is sufficient estimator when $\theta_1=0$ but what  about when $\theta_1\neq0$? Is $\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2$ sufficient?.

